# How to clear offline website cache in IE11?

Tags: internet-explorer, browser-cache

My site has  references to othersite.com. In order to block these reference I've added othersite to etc/hosts with nonexistent IP address, so IE can't open http://othersite.com any more. But when I reload my site in IE, I still see successfull AJAX calls to othersite.com. It looks like IE uses cached some data for this case. How can I clear it also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What helped me: finding folder with temporary internet files, deleting its content *and* rebooting Windows. IE is part of Windows 7, so I had to reboot it.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Tools, Safety, Delete Browsing History..., check Temporary Internet files and website files, click Delete:
[image]

For more information check [RefreshYourCache.com](http://www.refreshyourcache.com/en/internet-explorer-11/) and [View and delete your browsing history in Internet Explorer](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17438/windows-internet-explorer-view-delete-browsing-history#) Microsoft page.

Comment: This doesn't work for offline website history, I've tried this as you can see from my question.

Comment: You didn't mention that. Have you tried to clear DNS cache?

Comment: No, but since browser was not able to load site directly, dns was not the problem.